# Connected app and oauth in a SSO enabled org

Tags: apex, api, single-sign-on, oauth, connected-apps

I am working with a co worker and he is using connected app and all is setup fine (assuming?) He has client secret/ customer Key etc.. Since my org is single sign on enabled will I still use https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize? (or) use [http://sF.orgname.com](http://SF.orgrname.com)(openly accessible SSO portal for users) ?

In the connected app "Selected OAuth Scopes" do I need to use :

Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token)
Access and manage your data (api)
(or) 
Access and manage your data (api) should be good to authenticate the user?

Can someone throw light on how to auth in to a SSO enabled salesforce instance from a connected app using Oauth? **In short what should the redirect URL be when he is trying to authenticate into salesforce to get the access_token initially?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth URL can stay the same. I suspect you can also use https://MyDomain.my.salesforce.com/services/Oauth2/authorize

OAuth scopes will depend on what you intend doing via your app, but what you've described there should be okay.

Also, under Manage Apps, you will be able to set the level of access to your Connected App, whether you intend for all users to be able to authorise individually, or you want to pre-authorise certain admin approved users.

Comment: Using https://MyDomain.my.salesforce.com/services/Oauth2/authorize helped me auth in to the SSO org. I changed the callback URL in the connected app, I think the changes took a while to be published. It took almost 12+ hours before I could resolve the redirect_url should match error. Though I never knew I could use Domainname.salesforce.com. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: can you help me and my coworker with this question, would be a huge favor if you an: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/why-does-oauth2-authorization-endpoint-redirect-to-callback-url-as-if-it-were-th thanks in advance